# C++ spaceship-operator and user-defined types: comparing a subset of attributes only

Tags: c++, sorting, c++20, equality

I have two classes. The first one composing the second one. Both classes have its own synthetized attribute that doesn't collaborate to either ordering or comparision. In addition, I want to use`std::ranges::sort` over a container of the second one, so I need to implement a strong-ordering. That's what I have:

```
struct basic
{
    std::string synthetized; // string representation of the next field.
    unsigned value;
    unsigned property;

    friend bool operator<(basic const& a, basic const& b)
    { return a.value < b.value or (a.value == b.value and a.property < b.property); }
};

struct composed
{
   basic value;
   custom_type meta;

   friend bool operator<(composed const& a, composed const& b)
   { return a.value < b.value; }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<composed> container;
   // populating container

   // Compilation error here.
   std::ranges::sort(container);
}
```

How should I appropiately efficiently overload `operator<=>`? Although what I need is to sort the vector and that's it (I could just go to traditional `std::sort`), I want to know how to give to both classes full relational capabilities (<, <=, ==, !=, etc) to both classes, but ignoring `synthetized` and `meta`, and without doing anything stupid performance-wise.

Comment: You write the spaceship operator instead of `operator<`...?

Comment: It will compare the string and meta, and they don't want that to happen. Besides, `meta` is not even comparable at all.

Comment: Do you know you can write a custom `operator<=>`?

Comment: It's cute that you define your structs to be their own friends but utterly pointless and the signature for the operators is all wrong. In-class operators have `this` as implicit argument so they only take a single argument, the right hand side.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It's just a pattern I'm used to. Anyway, if you implement the `operator<` as a function member you disallow automatic conversion of the left object. For example, in case `composed` had a conversion constructor for an integer, `3 < x` won't work, while `<` as an external overload will. The point of making it friend has two reasons: 1. It's automatically inline. 2. In case their members were private, you have access without forward declarations required. These are classical well-known reasons of why operators are implemented that way (it's called the canonical implementation)

Comment: @Peregring-lk Works just fine with a member operator: https://godbolt.org/z/KdnTvqGMb

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ok, that's new. Change the compilation flag C++20 by C++17 in your godbolt. In C++17 (and before) doesn't work so I don't exactly know what has changed but that's a newly introduced relaxation of rules.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow no, when declare as `friend` it's not a member anymore. no `this` is implied and the signature in this post is all good.

Comment: @Peregring-lk are you misread my comment as GoswinvonBrederlow's? I'm just saying @ GoswinvonBrederlow. said something wrong. (and I'm not GoswinvonBrederlow)

Comment: @appleapple haha sorry. Yes I misread your comment as Goswin's. Deleting the comment now.

Comment: @appleapple I realized that later when I tried it out. But they do seem to be identical to member operators at least in c++20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How should I appropiately efficiently overload `operator<=>`?

The simplest way to do both would probably be to use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) and use the existing function template for [`operator<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) for `tuple` types:

```
template< class... TTypes, class... UTypes >
constexpr /* see link */ operator<=>( const std::tuple<TTypes...>& lhs,
                                      const std::tuple<UTypes...>& rhs );
```

Example:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct basic {
    std::string synthetized; // excluded from comparisons
    unsigned value;
    unsigned property;

    friend auto operator<=>(basic const& a, basic const& b) {
        return std::tie(a.value, a.property) <=> std::tie(b.value, b.property);
    }
};

struct composed {
    basic value;
    custom_type meta; // excluded from comparisons

    friend auto operator<=>(composed const& a, composed const& b) {
        return a.value <=> b.value;
    }
};
```

You should also add `operator==` which will also be used for `!=` so you don't have to overload `operator!=`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know how to give to both classes full relational
> capabilities (<, <=, ==, !=, etc) to both classes, but ignoring
> synthetized and meta, and without doing anything stupid
> performance-wise.

Define comparison member functions for your type

```
#include <string>

struct basic
{
    std::string synthetized; // string representation of the next field.
    unsigned value;
    unsigned property;

    constexpr auto operator<=>(const basic& other) const noexcept {
      if (auto c = value <=> other.value; c != 0) 
        return c;
      return property <=> other.property;
    }

    constexpr bool operator==(const basic& other) const noexcept {
      return value == other.value && property == other.property;
    }
};

struct composed
{
   basic value;
   custom_type meta;

   constexpr auto operator<=>(const composed& other) const noexcept {
    return value <=> other.value; 
   }

   constexpr bool operator==(const composed& other) const noexcept {
    return value == other.value; 
   }
};
```

Note that in your example `operator<=>` does not synthesize `operator==` because it is not the default, so you still need to define `operator==` for your type to satisfy [`total_ordered_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/totally_ordered).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7MeqbqGeE)

Comment: You can default `operator==` or `operator!=` and it will use `<=>` for everything.

Comment: How about `struct composed : basic { custom_type meta; using basic::operator<=>; using  basic::operator==;};`?

Comment: @Goswin Defaulting `==` will _not_ use `<=>`, it will generate member-wise equality.

Comment: @Barry Damn, I read that wrong. The part about defaulting an operator@ will make it use `<=>` only applies to `< > <= >=`.